# Cypress failed to make a connection to the Chrome DevTools Protocol: ECONNREFUSED at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect

Tags: chrome-devtools-protocol, cypress

I'm simply trying to run some of the tests in the example folder under Integration and it will not run on Chrome. Runs on Electron and Edge but refuses to run on Chrome and throwing the attached error after unsuccessfully trying.

My version of Chrome is Version 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Current Cypress version is - cypress": "^5.5.0

[image: Error launching browser]

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this issue on mac and I just had to hard quite Chrome and relaunch it. I didn't have to uninstall and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes when there is something wrong with your localhost configurations. Please check etc/hosts file.

You can refer to [this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5912) link for further clarifications.